# How do I initialize an atomic_flag data member?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm trying to implement a spin lock using an `atomic_flag`. I know that with C++11, I have to initialize the `atomic_flag` data member, but I can't get it to compile. My code looks like this:

```
class SpinLock 
{
 public:
  SpinLock()
   :m_flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT)  /// syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
  {
  }

  void lock()
  {
    while (m_flag.test_and_set() == true){}
  }

  void unlock()
  {
    m_flag.clear();
  }

 private:
  SpinLock &operator=(const SpinLock &);

 private:
  std::atomic_flag    m_flag;
};
```

When I compile the code I get

> 'syntax error : missing ')' before '{''.

I also see that `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is defined as `{0}`, but what is the correct way to write this then?

The following compiles, but is it still threads safe?

```cpp
SpinLock()
{
    m_flag.clear();
}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Your code should compile fine.

Comment: This does not compile in MSVC 2013 RC and RTM. (It did compile in Preview however). I filed a connect bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800243/visual-studio-2013-rc-std-atomic-flag-regression but have not heard back. In the meantime, for my code, I have used std::atomic<bool> and replaced test_and_set with exchange(true) and clear with store(false)

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2012

Comment: @arno ah, you need a C++11 compiler.

Comment: unfortunately I have to use VS2012 for now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 does not support c++11 initializer lists ([see the c++11 support page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx))

It is however supported in Visual Studio 2013, (see the "initializer_list Constructors" section in the [Uniform Initialization docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn387583.aspx))

Meanwhile in your case the constructor can just use an assignment `m_flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;`

**Update:**
It seems it did not test the above assignment, but using `m_flag.clear();` achieves the same result

Comment: The problem here is that `atomic_flag` has no assignment operator, so initializing the flag with `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` in the constructor body is not possible either. The correct way would be to initialize the flag using the default constructor (which leaves its state unspecified) and then call `.clear()` to set the state. This is indeed an annoying bug of the VS implementation.

Comment: I'm trying it like this, but not sure if the flag initialisation is still threadsafe

Comment: Since you are still in the SpinLock constructor then no other thread has access to the flag yet because your object "does not yet exist".

Comment: @ComicSansMS The inability to initialize atomic_flag as described is not a VS bug, it's a [restriction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) on atomic_flag.

Comment: @evoskuil You are of course right, this is not a bug in VS. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

It really looks like a bug ( visual 2013 rtm ). `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is implementation specific and solve as a macro to `{0}`. It means that Microsoft uses aggregate rules to do the job.

Quote from cppreference about them : `Until C++11, aggregate initialization could not be used in a constructor initializer list due to syntax restrictions.`. I conclude that Microsoft do not yet change this behavior.

Here an exemple working fine on clang and failing on VS2013 RTM with a simpler case :

```
struct Pod {
  int m_val;
};

Pod g_1{ 0 }; // aggregate initialization
Pod g_2{ { 0 } }; // just like ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT

struct Foo {
  Foo() : m_2 { 0 } {} // error C2664: 'Pod::Pod(const Pod &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Pod &'
  Pod m_1{ 0 }; // error C2664: 'Pod::Pod(const Pod &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Pod &'
  Pod m_2; // ok
};
```