# Workaround for error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

the following code does not compile with Visual Studio 2013 while it should:

```
class A
{
    A() :m_array{ 0, 1, 2 } {} // error C2536: 'A::A::m_array' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
private:
    int m_array[3];
};
```

See [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792161/constructor-initializer-list-does-not-support-braced-init-list-form) for more details.

**What are the possible workarounds?**

Comment: Does initialization at the point of declaration work? `int m_array[3]{1,2,3};`?

Comment: Does `std::array` work? (You'll need extra braces, unless the compiler has jumped the gun on C++14).

Comment: @juanchopanza: same error with VC++ 2013.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: could you be more specific please?

Comment: Declare array as `std::array<int, 3> m_array;` and initialize it as `A() :m_array ({ 0, 1, 2 }) {}`. Does it work or not?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the same problem found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19659756/2694444, visual studio 2013 compiler do not support aggregate initialization in the constructor initialization list either with non static member initialization. A bug report is also alive on connect.microsoft.com, but this is more a missing feature request than a bug.

Comment: @galop1n OP is asking for workarounds to this problem.

Comment: @MM. Yes, it works now, thanks! Can you elaborate an answer on the differences between the initial code and the workarounds you and Mike proposed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the comments, you can try this workaround.

```
class A
{
    A() : m_array ({ 0, 1, 2 }) {}
private:
    std::array<int, 3> m_array;
};
```

It seems VS2013 made initializer-list for `std::array` constructor well and you can initialize it in constructor's intializer. The code that you wrote is valid and both gcc and clang support it. VS2013 lacks.

Comment: I had to use an extra pair of braces in the constructor for this to compile in VS2013. A() : m_array ({ { 0, 1, 2 } })