# Error: cannot specify explicit initializer for array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studios 2013 and I keep getting this error yet I don't understand why.

```
class CLI{
    string commands[2] = {"create", "login"};
public:
    void addCommand(), start(), getCommand(string);
};
```

The error:

```
error C2536: 'CLI::CLI::commands': cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
```

Comment: It [should work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb3636698f1c9270). Out of curiosity, does [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e5fc954da32c146) work for you?

Comment: I won't ask what this is supposed to be: `void addCommand(), start(), getCommand(string);`, since it isn't related to your question.

Comment: You cannot initialize class members in this way before C++11. You need to do it in a constructor instead.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt, Sure you can; check my first link (and change 1y to 11 if you don't believe me).

Comment: @chris: I said _before_ C++11.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt. Ah, sorry, read that as "with C++11". I probably skipped a word or something.

Comment: @chris It probably doesn't matter as VS is notoriously immune to standards.

Comment: @TobiasBrandt, It's getting better. They are actually putting in a big effort to get caught up in that regard. I'm guessing VS2015 will be (nearly?) finished with C++14, which is much better than they did for C++11 at least. VS2014 should have most of it, too.

Comment: @chris Nope, the other method doesn't work; same exact error.

Comment: Interesting. I know uniform initialization is implemented, and so are in-class initializers. Interesting that this isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894398/cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 is not completely C++11 compliant, so, like Tobias Brandt said, you'll need to use a constructor to initialize those members.

Braced init lists are a C++11 feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that in-class member initializers are implemented in VC2013. Instead, initialize the array in a constructor. For example:

```
class CLI{
    string commands[2];
public:
    CLI() : commands {"create", "login"}
    {}
};
```

Comment: I get the same error involving "cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays" when using the constructor

Comment: It's not supported then. You'll have to initialize it in the constructor then. e.g "CLI(){commands[0] = "create";commands[1] = "login";}"