# How can I initialize an array

Tags: c++

I'm new to CPP, can't find a simple documentation on how to declare a **private constant class attribute**, and if it should go on the `.h` or `.m`

Here's what I have on my `Horse.h`:

```
class Horse {
    private:
        static const int body_vertex_quantity = 24;
        float left_ear_vertex_array[ears_vertex_quantity][2] = {
            //
        };
    public:
        draw();
}
```

But I'm getting

```
cannot specify explicit initializer of arrays
```

I have made my research in the following links, but I don't understand the syntax or what they're doing since I'm new to **cpp**

[Initializing a member array in constructor initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057948/initializing-a-member-array-in-constructor-initializer)

[Error: cannot specify explicit initializer for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900191/error-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-array)

[Workaround for error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877757/workaround-for-error-c2536-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays-in-vi)

[cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894398/cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays)

Comment: The second member isn't `static`.

Comment: .h or .m? Aren't .m files for Objective-C, not C++? And if you wanted Objective-C++, that's a .mm file, right?

Comment: Do this `left_ear_vertex_array {
            //
        }` in the member initializer list of a constructor function, not in the declaration!

Comment: variables cannot be used to declare array size.
Instead make it `float left_ear_vertex_array[24][2]`

Comment: If possible, use [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) and its [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), otherwise use `std::vector`