# Initialize a two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm learning C++ and I have a problem. I have this declaration in a class header file:

```
double bgal[3][3] =
    { { -0.066988739415,-0.872755765852,-0.483538914632 },
    { 0.492728466075,-0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 },
    { -0.867600811151,-0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 } };
```

With Visual Studio 2015 compiles fine, but with Visual Studio 2013 it doesn't compile. I get this message:

```
cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays
```

I think the problem is related that Visual Studio 2013 doesn't support C++11 and Compiler Error C2536.

I have tried to move that initialization inside the class constructor, but it doesn't work. This:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : bgal { { -0.066988739415, -0.872755765852, -0.483538914632 }, 
                            { 0.492728466075, -0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 },
                            { -0.867600811151, -0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 } }
```

But it doesn't work.

Any advice? Maybe I can't make this vector constant or static, or...

I have tried `bgal[0][0] = { ...}; bgal[0][1] = { ...};` but it is a lot of work.

It is not a duplicate of question [Error: cannot specify explicit initializer for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900191/error-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-array) because that question asks about a one dimension array, and it offers as a solution to initialize the array with `bgal[0][0] = { ...}; bgal[0][1] = { ...};` that it is a lot of work. And I asking if there is another way to do it faster.

Please read the question carefully before looking for possible duplicate questions.

Comment: Don't you have to set a compiler setting explicitly for VS2013 to enable C++11?

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski Please, read my update. I have found that question before ask mine, and its solution is on my question, and I'm asking if there is another solution.

Comment: @MrLister I'm going to use this lib with Unreal Engine and I'm not sure if I can enable C++ 11. I will check it. As Microsoft said, I don't have to do anything special to enable C++ 11 features in Visual Studio 2013, so it doesn't support explicit array initialization.

Comment: @VansFannel There is also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877757/workaround-for-error-c2536-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays-in-vi which seems to point out that this is a VS bug O_o

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski Is std::array equivalent to double bgal[3][3] array?

Comment: @MrLister no, you don't

Comment: Tell Microsoft to give you a real C compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing discussion from comments, and according to this question: [Workaround for error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877757/workaround-for-error-c2536-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays-in-vi)

you can use something like this, altho its not as pretty as raw array or arrays

```
array<array<double, 3>, 3> a({
    array<double,3>({ -0.066988739415,-0.872755765852,-0.483538914632 }),
    array<double,3>({ 0.492728466075,-0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 }),
    array<double,3>( { -0.867600811151,-0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 }) });
```

To make it a little prettier you can always define a helper macro

```
#define DD array<double,3>

array<array<double, 3>, 3> a({
    DD({ -0.066988739415,-0.872755765852,-0.483538914632 }),
    DD({ 0.492728466075,-0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 }),
    DD( { -0.867600811151,-0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 }) });
#undef DD
```

You can always try to use vector of vectors with initialized list like this: https://ideone.com/lQ12a4

```
vector<vector<double> > a{
    { -0.066988739415,-0.872755765852,-0.483538914632 },
    { 0.492728466075,-0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 },
    { -0.867600811151,-0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 } };
```

I don't know if this will be working on your compiler but according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh567368.aspx it should.

Comment: Is that array equivalent to bgal[3][3]? In my code I'm using  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  pos1[i] = pos[0] * bgal[i][0] + pos[1] * bgal[i][1] + pos[2] * bgal[i][2];
 }

Comment: It is equivalent, your code should work because std::array has correctyle defined operator[], but you won't be able to cast directly to double[][]

Comment: I have used your code in my header file and I getting a lot of error. Where do I have to use your code?

Comment: @VansFannel What sort of error? to use std::array you need to include <array> header

Comment: at a({ <- type specifier he expected. At std::array<double, 3>({ <-- error expression expected. And at }) }); <-- ; expected.

Comment: @VansFannel  It would be better to open another question with this error I can post an answer there.

Comment: @VansFannel but you probably are missing #include <array> and/or std:: before array

Comment: No, I have  #include and std:: This code comes from a C library, and I have tried to convert it to C++. Maybe, I'm going to use it the C library and forget this port. I'm tired to try and try and get errors and more errors.

Comment: If I'm not going to modify those values, is there a way to define that matrix as constant?

Comment: Have you tried your code?

Comment: Check edits. I tried it but on GCC and Clang. Unfortunately I don't have Windows or Visual Studio

Comment: You can download Visual Studio 2013 community edition if  you want.

Comment: Here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12844625/68571, I have found how to make it works.

Comment: @VansFannel It is almost the same thing which I wrote, except i'm calling constructor explicitly and that answer is using initializer_list

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the data member initialization of an array type. You can select the method that allows to initialize the array using your compiler.:)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    double bgal[3][3] 
    { { -0.066988739415,-0.872755765852,-0.483538914632 },
      { 0.492728466075,-0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 },
      { -0.867600811151,-0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 } 
    };    
};

struct B
{
    B() : bgal { { -0.066988739415,-0.872755765852,-0.483538914632 },
                 { 0.492728466075,-0.450346958020, 0.744584633283 },
                 { -0.867600811151,-0.188374601723, 0.460199784784 } }
    {

    }

    double bgal[3][3];
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    for ( const auto &row : a.bgal )
    {
        for ( double x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( const auto &row : b.bgal )
    {
        for ( double x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
-0.0669887 -0.872756 -0.483539 
0.492728 -0.450347 0.744585 
-0.867601 -0.188375 0.4602 

-0.0669887 -0.872756 -0.483539 
0.492728 -0.450347 0.744585 
-0.867601 -0.188375 0.4602
```

It was compiled with the on-line MS compiler

Comment: But isn't online compiler using vs 2015?

Comment: If I do what are you suggesting in struct B I get the same error message.

Comment: @VansFannel Are you show that you copied and pasted my example?

Comment: @Bartosz Przybylski  The example allows to check whether a particular compiler will compile the program.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow could you post a link to this compiler?

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski Yes, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski  Here you are http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: @VansFannel Then it seems it is a compiler bug.

Comment: @VansFannel If the first example with struct A is compiled then you can initialize the array  as it is shown.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This website only shows compiler version, I don't know which compiler version is in VS13, so since it compiles on the website but on on computer, then I think that those versions are different

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski Maybe. I do not know.