# Can't specify explicit initializer for arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Why does this compile in VS 2013

```
int main()
{

    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    return 0;

}
```

but this gives the error

```
class TestClass
{

    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

};
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: AFAIK this is a C++11 feature that Microsoft hadn't implemented at the time of VS2013's release. It compiles with [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/744a928564817d8f) and [clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46cb648754583e84).

Comment: @ScottHunter "cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays".

Comment: @Borgleader Why does the first example compile and not the second? What is the workaround?

Comment: @abalter Because the former has been in the language since "forever" whereas the latter is a newer feature that's not been implemented yet (in VS). For the workaround see Cheers' answer.

Comment: @Borgleader So the difference is initializing in class scope vs in a method?

Comment: @abalter yep pretty much. I added a link with more info on this feature in my answer, if you're interested in reading more about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894398/cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From Bjarne's C++11 FAQ page](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init):

> In C++98, only static const members of integral types can be initialized in-class, and the initializer has to be a constant expression. [...] The basic idea for C++11 is to allow a non-static data member to be initialized where it is declared (in its class).

The problem is, VS2013 doesn't implement all the features of C++11, and this is one of them. So what I suggest you use is std::array (take note of the extra set of braces):

```
#include <array>

class A
{
public:
    A() : a({ { 1, 2, 3 } }) {} // This is aggregate initialization, see main() for another example

private:
    std::array<int, 3> a; // This could also be std::vector<int> depending on what you need.
};

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> std_ar2 { {1,2,3} };
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

[cppreference link on aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

If you're interested you can click [on this link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2686217d24b9d716) to see that what you did does compile when using a compiler that has implemented this feature (in this case g++, I've tried it on clang++ and it works too).

Answer (score 1):

Why: not yet implemented in that version of Visual C++.

Fix: use `std::array` and initialize in each constructor.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your example with an explicit example? I've tried a couple of things, but not found the correct way yet.

Comment: For instance, I tried `int a = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};`.

Comment: @abalter: you don't need `new` in C++, that's a Java thing.

Answer (score 0):

In alternative to using `std::array` as the other answers suggest, you can use the approach described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20894669/266309): mark the array as static in the class declaration (which would usually be in the header file), and initialize it in the source file. Like so:

**test.h:**

```
class TestClass
{
    static int a[3];
};
```

**test.cpp:**

```
int TestClass::a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Eventually, this should become unecessary as MSVC catches up to C++11.