# error C2536: : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm using visual studio 13. I just declared and initialized an unsigned long array.

```
 unsigned long z[8] = { 0xffffffff, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff };
```

But it throws the following error

> error C2536: : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

I read some answers related to this error but its not helping me. Can somebody help me solve this error?

Comment: Is that supposed to be class member? If yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882915/c-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays. If not, show more relevant code.

Comment: @R Sahu      Its a member of a structure.

Comment: I guess, it was addressed to you :) @RSahu

Comment: Post a complete example of your code so we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @vsoftco        My program is in c. All the examples shown are in C++ with classes. How the hell would it help me solve my problem in C with structures?

Comment: @vsoftco - You shouldn't do unjustice to OP by tagging duplicate of C++ question to a C question!!! Please reopen it.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful The question was tagged C++ initially though (as you can see from the edit history), otherwise I wouldn't have been able to close it. It was changed to `C` after I close it.

Comment: @abejoe You should have mentioned this when asking the question. You tagged it as C++. In any case, I voted to reopen. And please use a civilized tone.

Comment: @Anon Mail     Sorry I'm not allowed to post my entire code. Will you be able to help me out with just the information i give you?

Comment: @ vsoftco       Chill...Tat c++ tag was a mistake..before I could realize it, u marked it as duplicate!

Comment: @abejoe All right, I voted to reopen it. I cannot reopen now by myself since it is tagged C. Will tag it C++ again, reopen it, and delete the tag. Darn, still doesn't work.

Comment: @abejoe: You cannot specify initializers in structure declarations. It does not matter whether it is an array or anything else. There's simply no such thing as an "initializer" in that context. What do you expect it to initialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a "natural" context (i.e. an array object declaration) you declaration with initialization is perfectly valid. There's nothing wrong with it.

The only explanation for the error is that, as you noted in the comments, your array is declared as a struct member and you are trying to specify the initializer right in the struct declaration. Doing something like that just does not make any sense in C. You cannot specify initializers for members in struct declarations, regardless of whether these members are arrays or something else.

Initializers are supposed to be specified in object definitions, as in

```
struct S 
{
  unsigned long z[8];
};

struct S s = { { 0xffffffff, 0x00000001, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff } };
```

Comment: What if I need to define multiple arrays with different names under the same structure? I mean how to do that?