# Cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays in Windows Qt 5.7 (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qt-creator

Following up on a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649750/6167676), I am trying to get around an -apparanently common- error `**C2536 : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays**` for line `in line: QLineEdit * edits[3] = {&lineEditName, &lineEditGender, &lineEditRegion};`

I have read other solutions (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894398/cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882915/cant-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays)) but do not appear to apply in my case. I am using **Qt Creator 4.1.0 with Qt 5.7.0, MSVC 2013 in Windows with C++**. Any suggestions are welcome.

On an extra note, and in the interest of better understanding Qt with C++, could someone point to a **different way** -*instead of using arrays*- for holding the new parsed json results?

Below you can see the full code from that answer (the line in question is in `mainwindow.h`):

main.cpp

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/into-mainwin-39643510
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "controller.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   MainWindow ui;
   Controller ctl;
   QTimer timer;
   timer.start(5*1000);
   QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &ctl, &Controller::get);

   QObject::connect(&ctl, &Controller::busy, &ui, [&]{ ui.setState(MainWindow::Loading); });
   QObject::connect(&ui, &MainWindow::request, &ctl, &Controller::get);
   QObject::connect(&ctl, &Controller::error, &ui, [&]{ ui.setState(MainWindow::Error); });
   QObject::connect(&ctl, &Controller::values, &ui, &MainWindow::setFields);
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
```

controller.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QtNetwork>

class Controller : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QNetworkAccessManager manager{this};
   QNetworkRequest request;
   Q_SLOT void onReply(QNetworkReply *);
public:
   explicit Controller(QObject * parent = nullptr);
   Q_SLOT void get();
   Q_SIGNAL void busy();
   Q_SIGNAL void error(const QString &);
   Q_SIGNAL void values(const QString & name, const QString & gender, const QString & region);
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

controller.cpp

```
#include "controller.h"

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
   QUrlQuery query;
   query.addQueryItem("amount", "1");
   query.addQueryItem("region", "United States");
   QUrl url("http://uinames.com/api/");
   url.setQuery(query);
   request = QNetworkRequest(url);
   connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Controller::onReply);
}

void Controller::onReply(QNetworkReply * reply) {
   if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
      emit error(reply->errorString());
      manager.clearAccessCache();
   } else {
      //parse the reply JSON and display result in the UI
      auto jsonObject = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
      auto fullName = jsonObject["name"].toString();
      fullName.append(" ");
      fullName.append(jsonObject["surname"].toString());
      emit values(fullName, jsonObject["gender"].toString(), jsonObject["region"].toString());
   }
   reply->deleteLater();
}

void Controller::get() {
   emit busy();
   manager.get(request);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  QFormLayout layout{this};
  QLineEdit lineEditName;
  QLineEdit lineEditGender;
  QLineEdit lineEditRegion;
  QPushButton button{"Get Name"};
  QLineEdit * edits[3] = {&lineEditName, &lineEditGender, &lineEditRegion};
public:
  enum State { Normal, Loading, Error };
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
  Q_SLOT void setFields(const QString & name, const QString & gender, const QString & region);
  Q_SLOT void setState(State);
  Q_SIGNAL void request();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   for(auto edit : edits) edit->setReadOnly(true);
   layout.addRow("Name:", &lineEditName);
   layout.addRow("Gender:", &lineEditGender);
   layout.addRow("Region:", &lineEditRegion);
   layout.addRow(&button);
   connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::request);
}

void MainWindow::setFields(const QString & name, const QString & gender, const QString & region) {
   setState(Normal);
   lineEditName.setText(name);
   lineEditGender.setText(gender);
   lineEditRegion.setText(region);
}

void MainWindow::setState(MainWindow::State state) {
   if (state == Normal) {
      for (auto edit : edits) edit->setEnabled(true);
      button.setEnabled(true);
   }
   else if (state == Loading) {
      for (auto edit : edits) edit->setEnabled(false);
      button.setEnabled(false);
   }
   else if (state == Error) {
      for (auto edit : edits) edit->setText("Error...");
      button.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: What if: QLineEdit * edits[] {&lineEditName, &lineEditGender, &lineEditRegion};

Comment: @AlexanderVX No doesn't solve it either, it gives the same error along with `an array of unknown size cannot be used in a range-based for statement`. Any other suggestions or provide an alternative for the `edits` array altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MSVC2013 [does not support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) all C++11 features. The main issue here, is that you can't specify in-class initialization for member arrays.

The closest workaround in my opinion would be  to use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of the C array for `edits`, since MSVC2013 seems to support initializing an `std::array` using [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), you can replace your:

```
QLineEdit * edits[3] = {&lineEditName, &lineEditGender, &lineEditRegion};
```

to use `std::array` and aggregate initialization like this:

```
std::array<QLineEdit*,3> edits{{&lineEditName, &lineEditGender, &lineEditRegion}};
```

Note that you have to add `#include <array>` to your `mainwindow.h` to use `std::array`.

> On an extra note, and in the interest of better understanding Qt with
>   C++, could someone point to a different way -instead of using arrays-
>   for holding the new parsed json results?

You are not using *arrays* for holding the new parsed json results, this is just how you use `QJsonObject`.

If you are looking for a way to further separate JSON parsing in its own class. You might want to have some class (eg. `NameData`) that encapsulates the name's data (`fullName`, `gender`, `region`), and provides a way to be constructed out of a `QByteArray` of JSON data.

This way the `Controller` class does not know anything about JSON, it just uses the `NameData` class to parse the reply it has from the network.

you may implement it like this:

namedata.h

```
#ifndef NAMEDATA_H
#define NAMEDATA_H

#include <QtCore>

class NameData
{
public:
    QString fullName;
    QString gender;
    QString region;

    static NameData fromReplyByteArray(QByteArray byteArray);
};

#endif // NAMEDATA_H
```

namedata.cpp

```
#include "namedata.h"

NameData NameData::fromReplyByteArray(QByteArray byteArray){
    QJsonObject jsonObject = QJsonDocument::fromJson(byteArray).object();
    NameData result;
    result.fullName = jsonObject["name"].toString();
    result.fullName.append(" ");
    result.fullName.append(jsonObject["surname"].toString());
    result.gender= jsonObject["gender"].toString();
    result.region= jsonObject["region"].toString();
    return result;
}
```

Now, the `onReply` function in `Controller` class, should be:

```
void Controller::onReply(QNetworkReply * reply) {
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        emit error(reply->errorString());
        manager.clearAccessCache();
    } else {
        //parse the reply JSON and display result in the UI (using the separate class)
        NameData nameData= NameData::fromReplyByteArray(reply->readAll());
        emit values(nameData.fullName, nameData.gender, nameData.region);
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```