# initialize class array in initialization list c++

Tags: c++, arrays, list, class, initialization

I have this class:

```
class Taxi {
   Wheel myWheel[4];
public:
   Taxi();
};
```

and Wheel is another class contain:

```
class Wheel{
   int radius,
       tickness;
public:
   Wheel(int,int);
};
```

now, what i want to do is to initialize "myWheel[4]" in initialization list of Taxi constructor, like this:

```
Taxi::Taxi () :Wheel[0](5,5), Wheel[1](3,3), Wheel[2](5,5), Wheel[3](3,3) {
   cout << "Ctor of Taxi" << endl;
}
```

but it doesn't work and i really need some HELP,
thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your initialization list should look like

```
Taxi::Taxi () : myWheel { Wheel(5,5), Wheel(3,3), Wheel(5,5), Wheel(3,3)} {
   cout << "Ctor of Taxi" << endl;
}
```

See a ***[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/rjqGjX)***

If you don't have a compiler compliant with the current c++ standard (c++11), there's no way to do this in the member initializer list. You have to initialize the array elements inside the constructor's body:

```
Taxi::Taxi () {
   cout << "Ctor of Taxi" << endl;
   myWheel[0] = Wheel(5,5);
   myWheel[1] = Wheel(3,3);
   myWheel[2] = Wheel(5,5); 
   myWheel[3] = Wheel(3,3);
}
```

Also note you should make `Wheel` a [*nice class*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Nice_Class) then.

Comment: it doesn't work :/
errors:
-only '()' is allowed as initializer for array member "AutoTaxi::_taxiWheel"
-expected a declaration
-expected a ';' 
-'AutoTaxi::AutoTaxi::_taxiWheel' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

Comment: @Naama Well, the linked demo works. Are you sure to have replicated the code correctly? I had to fix some other errors until it worked. Also note the order of declaration for `Wheel` and `Taxi`. What's your compiler version language standard flags actually?

Comment: @Naama, this requires C++11

Comment: It's not the same code because class taxi has more varient but without this code it's working perfectly but when i try to initialize wheel it's starting to show errors

Comment: @ChrisDrew what do u mean c++11?

Comment: #πάντα ῥεῖ Sorry for the ignorance but I don't know how to check compiler version.
I know I'm using visual studio pro 2013 version 12.0.21

Comment: Check this Q&A then please: [Workaround for error C2536: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877757/workaround-for-error-c2536-cannot-specify-explicit-initializer-for-arrays-in-vi). It looks like VS2013 (_supporting_ c++11 by default) is broken about this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank u very much for helping me,
now it's working :D

Answer (score 3):

You can only initialize arrays if you have a C++11 capable compiler, and then you can do

```
Taxi::Taxi () :myWheel{{5,5}, {3,3}, {5,5}, {3,3}} { ... }
```

If you don't have a C++11 capable compiler, then you have to initialize the array manually:

```
Taxi::Taxi()
{
    myWheel[0] = Wheel(5, 5);
    myWheel[1] = Wheel(3, 3);
    myWheel[2] = Wheel(5, 5);
    myWheel[3] = Wheel(3, 3);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work as well..
error: cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

Comment: I don't think the second variant is legal C++.

Comment: Everyone are correct, it was not valid in pre-C++11. Updated my answer