# Simple Spinlock with atomic does not compile

Tags: c++, atomic, spinlock

I came across that simple Spinlock which also works with the lock_guard to hold the RAII conventions:

```
#include <atomic>
class SpinLock
{
private:
    std::atomic_flag lck = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

public:
    inline SpinLock(){};
    ~SpinLock(){};

    inline void lock(){
        while (lck.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
        {
        }
    }

    inline void unlock()
    {
        lck.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }
};
```

But this does not compile.

```
Error   1   6   error C2664: 'std::atomic_flag::atomic_flag(const std::atomic_flag &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const std::atomic_flag &' ...\spinlock.h  1   ShortDB
```

Can someone explain why? There are alot of that examples out there which do exactly the same. (for example [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic_flag/))

---

Edit:
The makro streight from the atomic VS2013:

```
// STRUCT atomic_flag
#define ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT    {0}
```

Comment: I suspect some neanderthal has defined `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` to be `{0}` rather than `{false}`. Check your macro and post it in your question. clang 3.5 on OS X 10.10.2 has it as `#define ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT {false}`

Comment: Sounds like you should rather initialize `lck` in your member initializer list:: `SpinLock() : lck(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {};`

Comment: If i do it in init list i get `Error 1 9 error C2280: 'std::atomic_flag::atomic_flag(const std::atomic_flag &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function d:\git repo\shortdb\projekt\shortdb\shortdb\spinlock.h 1 ShortDB` Already tested that.

Yes the marko is {0} add it

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I initialise an atomic\_flag variable if it is a member of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657222/how-do-i-initialise-an-atomic-flag-variable-if-it-is-a-member-of-a-class)

Comment: @Caramiriel Thanks got it with the.clear command. I simply call the `lck.clear(std::memory_order_release);` in the ctor.